# Fatal error in Constructor controller in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, customer-session

I am creating sub user for current logged in customer

below is my controller code

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages;
class CreatePost extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $helperData;
protected $_fieldsetConfig;
protected $_customerSession; 
protected $customerFactory;
protected $_objectManager;
protected $_customer; 
protected $_messageManager;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Inkind\Customer\Helper\Data $helperData,
    \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy\Config $fieldsetConfig,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession, 
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
) {
    $this->helperData = $helperData;
    $this->_fieldsetConfig = $fieldsetConfig;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession; 
    $this->customerFactory  = $customerFactory;
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager; 
    $this->_customer = $customer; 
    $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    parent::__construct($context);
}    
public function execute()
{       
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $user = $this->customerFactory->setId(null);
        //$user = $this->_customer->setId(null);
        $customerSession = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory')->create(); 
        $master_id = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getMasterId();
        $master = $this->customerFactory->load($master_id); 
        //$data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $defaultFields = array();
        $customerAccount = $this->_fieldsetConfig->getFieldset('customer_account');

        foreach ($customerAccount as $code=>$node) {
            $defaultFields[] = $code;
            if ($node->is('create') && isset($data[$code])) {
                if ($code == 'email') {
                    $data[$code] = trim($data[$code]);
                }
                $user->setData($code, $data[$code]);
            }
        }

        $customerattr = $this->helperData->getCustomerUserDefinedAttributes();
        foreach ($customerattr as $_customerattr) {
            if (isset($data[$_customerattr->getAttributeCode()]) && (!in_array($_customerattr, $defaultFields))) {
                $user->setData($_customerattr->getAttributeCode(), $data[$_customerattr->getAttributeCode()]);
            }
        }

        foreach ($this->_getSharedFields() as $_att) {
            $user->setData($_att, $master->getData($_att));
        }

        try {           
            $user->save();              

            $this->_messageManager->addSuccess(__('User was successfully created.'));

            return $this->_redirect('inkindcustomer/subuser/listuser/');

        }catch (\Exception $e){
           $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e->getMessage());
           $this->_messageManager->addError(__('We were unable to submit your request. Please try again!'));
           return $this->_redirect('inkindcustomer/subuser/listuser/');
        }       

    }

}
```

Getting error on these two lines,

```
  $user = $this->customerFactory->setId(null);
```

and in line

```
 if ($node->is('create') && isset($data[$code])) {
```

as 
  PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is() on array

Please anyone advise me on these issues.

Here is my template file content

```
 <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('inkindcustomer/subuser/createpost') ?>" method="post" id="newuser_form">

 <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $FormKey->getFormKey();?>">
<div class="fieldset">
<h2 class="legend"><?php echo 'User Information'; ?></h2>
<ul class="form-list">

    <li>
        <label for="firstname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'First Name'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" title="<?php echo 'First Name'; ?>" data-validate="{required:true}" class="input-text required-entry" maxlength="24" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="lastname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'Last Name'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" title="<?php echo 'Last Name'; ?>" data-validate="{required:true}" class="input-text required-entry"  maxlength="24" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'Email Address'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo 'Email Address'; ?>" data-validate="{required:true}" class="input-text required-entry validate-email"  maxlength="200" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'Phone No.'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo 'Phone No.'; ?>" class="input-text required-entry" maxlength="30" data-validate="{required:true}" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="job_title" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'Job Title/Position'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="job_title" id="job_title" title="<?php echo 'Job Title/Position'; ?>" class="input-text required-entry"  maxlength="50" data-validate="{required:true}" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="department"><?php echo 'Department'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="department" id="department" title="<?php echo 'Department'; ?>" class="input-text" maxlength="50" data-validate="{required:true}" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <?php 
            $options[] = array('value' => '', 'code'    => 'Please select...');
            $options[] = array('value' => 1, 'code' => 'Account Controller');
            $options[] = array('value' => 2, 'code' => 'Order Authorisation');
        ?>
        <label for="user_level" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo 'Access Level'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <select name="user_level" id="user_level" title="<?php echo 'Access Level'; ?>" class="validate-select required-entry" >
                <?php foreach ($options as $_option): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $_option['value']?>"><?php echo $_option['code'] ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <?php $currency = '£'; ?>
        <label for="order_limit"><?php echo 'Order Value Limit'; ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="order_limit" id="order_limit" title="<?php echo 'Order Value Limit'; ?>" class="input-text validate-currency validate-number" maxlength="10" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

***
                
                    
                
            
            
                ***

```
  <div class="buttons-set form-buttons">      
  <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo 'Save'; ?>"><span> 
    <span><?php echo 'Save'; ?></span></span></button>
  </div>
<p class="required"><?php echo '* Required Fields'; ?></p>
```

Comment: what error your are getting?

Comment: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is() on array

Comment: you should use `isset($node['create'])` or `($node->Create())` instead of `$node->is('create')`
You can check same in `vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/Customer/Collection.php`  at line number 117 to 122

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code from:

```
foreach ($customerAccount as $code=>$node) {
                $defaultFields[] = $code;
                if ($node->is('create') && isset($data[$code])) {
                    if ($code == 'email') {
                        $data[$code] = trim($data[$code]);
                    }
                    $user->setData($code, $data[$code]);
                }
            }
```

To:

```
    foreach ($customerAccount as $code=>$node) {
        $defaultFields[] = $code;
        if ((isset($node['create'])) && (isset($data[$code]))) {
            if ($code == 'email') {
                $data[$code] = trim($data[$code]);
            }
            $user->setData($code, $data[$code]);
        }
    }
```

You can check same in `vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/Customer/Collection.php` at line number 117 to 122

Also your code should be from :

```
$user = $this->customerFactory->setId(null);
```

To:

```
$user = $this->customerFactory->create()->setId(null);
```

Comment: Yes, one this resolved the error but customer is not creating, it is updating old customer

Comment: How can we create new customer? Its updating old customer

Comment: try wih this vendor/magento/module-customer/Api/AccountManagementInterface.php

Comment: Please update me the code.

Comment: Add this in cunstruct `AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,` and then share customer object at `$customer = $this->accountManagement
                ->createAccount($customer, $password, $redirectUrl);` you can check code at `vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php`

Comment: I found another correction in your code which I have update in answer please review that also may be it will solve your issue.

Comment: Welcome!! happy to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81263/discussion-between-jafar-and-kunj).